# Initialize empty database from SQL scripts generated by Redgate SQL Source Control

Tags: sql-server, integration-testing, redgate

I have a folder with SQL scripts generated by Redgate SQL Source Control:

[image]

I want to create a new SQL server database on the CI server to run integration tests as a part of the pipeline. I can easily create a new SQL server docker container. But then I need to create all tables, function etc. I want to use SQL scripts generated by Redgate SSC but I don't see the way to run them in the pipeline. I tried to run them manually but it's quite hard because it requires to run them in a proper sequence because there are dependencies between different SQL objects.

Is there a known way to do it?

**UPDATE:** Currently I'm looking into [Building a Database Directly from Object-level Source Scripts](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-compare/building-a-database-directly-from-object-level-source-scripts) approach.

Comment: This can be incredibly complicated if you have inline functions calling each other etc, doesn't Redgate tool creates proper sequence already? But in worst case, it should work running the scripts more than once, until all dependencies are satisfied?

Comment: We use database projects in visual studio for this.

Comment: `DBCC CLONEDATABASE` will clone the schema of a DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scripts Folder created by SQL Source Control represents the create statements but to build a new database they need to be ordered correctly. SQL Compare Pro can be used to read in a scripts folder as its source [using /scripts1](https://documentation.red-gate.com/sc/using-the-command-line/switches-used-in-the-command-line#Switchesusedinthecommandline-/Scripts1:%3Cfolder%3E), and if you set the target ([/s2](https://documentation.red-gate.com/sc/using-the-command-line/switches-used-in-the-command-line#Switchesusedinthecommandline-/Server2:%3Cservername%3E) and [/db2](https://documentation.red-gate.com/sc/using-the-command-line/switches-used-in-the-command-line#Switchesusedinthecommandline-/Database2:%3Cdatabasename%3E)) to be your empty database, it will create (and apply if you use the [/sync](https://documentation.red-gate.com/sc/using-the-command-line/switches-used-in-the-command-line#Switchesusedinthecommandline-/Synchronize)) a deployment script to create your database. The SQL Compare Pro CLI comes with SQL Toolbelt Essentials or Flyway Enterprise, and is available as a traditional command line executable as well as [from Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/redgate/sqlcompare). Please contact support@red-gate.com if you're unsure about licensing.

Here is an example:

```
sqlcompare /scripts1:"C:\Scripts Folder\" /s2:"my_server\my_instance,myport;encrypt=true;trustservercertificate=true" /db2:MyTargetDB /sync
```